# A random()-like function without random()

Tags: javascript

Can I write a JavaScript function from scratch that behaves like `Math.random`?

(By that I mean without using `Math.random`.)

Comment: Every reasonable [pseudo-random number generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) needs to maintain _state_ between calls -- either in an object or via global variables. Will you have either an object that your clients will re-use or access to global variables that persist between calls?

Comment: No. Does `Math.random` maintain state?

Comment: Not until you gain a deep understanding of generating random numbers... especially if you intend to do crypto.

Comment: @sarnold: but thanks to closures in JavaScript you can maintain state in a plain old function, so there's no need for either a separate object or a global variable.  (Unless of course you want separate generators with separate seeds and/or states.)

Comment: @Maerics: Awesome! I had no idea JavaScript was _that_ nice. :)

Comment: @Randomblue: _probably_ `Math.random()` uses a simple [Linear Congruential Generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) because the state that must be stored is quite small and the data is good enough for no-stakes poker or mathematical randomness needs. But perhaps it uses a tool such as [`/dev/random`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/urandom), in which case the operating system is in charge of storing the state between executions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, you can implement your own [LCG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) number generator, but as Sarnold mentions you need to maintain state between calls.

Comment: So does `Math.random` maintain state in some way or another?

Comment: @Randomblue I am not sure if Math.random does, but a LCG algorithm uses the previous value to generate the next one.

Comment: Without maintaining state (or recursion in other words) it is impossible to generate randomness. All random number generators are in fact highly chaotic and thus deterministic processes.

Answer (score 2):

Per @OscarGomez's answer regarding a [linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator), here's an example of a random number generator as a plain JavaScript function.  Of course, its quality of "randomness" (currently very poor due to a short cycle) appears to be dependent on picking good values for the constants in the enclosed object "o".

```javascript
var random = (function() {
  var o = {mod: 13, mul: 11, inc: 7, x: 0};
  return function() {
    return o.x = (o.mul * o.x + o.inc) % o.mod
  }
})();
random(); // => 7
random(); // => 6
random(); // => 8
random(); // => 4
```

Here's a more portable version which can have separate generator instances and seeds:

```javascript
function Random(s) {
  this.seed = s || 0;
  this.mod = 13;
  this.mul = 11;
  this.inc = 7;
  this.x = this.seed;
}

Random.prototype.next = function() {
  return (this.x = (this.mul * this.x + this.inc) % this.mod);
};

var r = new Random(1);
r.next(); // => 5
r.next(); // => 10
r.next(); // => 7
```

Comment: i is safe to always use the miliseconds time for the seed `seed = new Date().getTime();`, or it will affect the randomness?

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do when I need some randomness but am to lazy to look up the syntax is to implement the [logistic map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map) (a discrete chaotic system). In pseudo code this is like this:

```
var x = 0.234;     // or some other number between 0 and 1 ( but not 0.5 )
for (var n=1; n<=100;n++){
   x = 4 * x * (1-x);   // this is the iteration
   console.log(x);
}
```

This would print 100 somehow random numbers, not really random but for many situations random enough.
Sorry for not giving a javascript answer, I havent used that for a decade.